Does searchkit not create a Smart Geoup with the search results like Search Builder does?
Does searchkit not create a Smart Geoup with the search results like Search Builder does ?
It seems to defeat the Smart Group idea to build a group with Searchkit based on all of a contact subtype with a given tag and then have to create a group and add the found contacts to that  group. A smart Group should apply the search criteria each time and find a current contacts satisfying the criteria - right ?
Am I missing something ?

The Add dropdown in the left column of the searchkit creation screen has a choice for smart group.
